# Trying to create a file to meet three conditions

Tags: command-line, ls, tr

I need to make a file that lists the first 5 lines of the `/sbin` directory, with having all 5 lines numbered AND all lines capitalized.

Here is one string of commands that I tried:

```
tr [a-z] [A-Z] < ls /sbin -n | head -5 > list.txt
```

However, that gave me this:

```
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash shell you can use this command:

```bsh
ls /sbin | head -n 5 | nl | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' > list.txt
```

How this works:

- `ls /sbin` lists the contents of `/sbin`. See [`man ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ls.1.html) for more options.
- The output is then piped to `head -n 5`, which keeps only the first 5 results. See [`man head`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/head.1posix.html) for more options.
- The output is then piped to `nl`, which numbers the output lines. See [`man nl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/nl.1posix.html) for more options.
- The output is then piped to `tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'`, which converts all lowercase characters to uppercase. See [`man tr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/tr.1.html) for more options.
- Finally, `> list.txt` is used to redirect the output to a file name `list.txt`.

The final output should be something similar to this:

```bsh
$ ls /sbin | head -n 5 | nl | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
     1  AA-REMOVE-UNKNOWN
     2  AA-STATUS
     3  AA-TEARDOWN
     4  ACCESSDB
     5  ACPID
```